# Creating a Dropdown with Form::select pulling more than one table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel, so excuse me if I'm being dumb :)

I have a table with MMA fighters.

I'm trying to pull a dropdown with their name + lname + nickname and put their id as the value.

So far I could do it just with the name.

This is my Controller

```
$fighters = Fighter::lists('name ', 'id');
return View::make ('fighters/create', ['fighters' => $fighters]);
```

And this is at my view

```
{{ Form::select('master', $fighters)}}
```

I'm trying to do it elegantly using Form:select rather than creating the code myself using foreach.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL's `CONCAT` function:

```
$fighters = Fighter::lists(DB::raw('CONCAT(name, lname, nickname) as name', 'id');
```